# How fix error "Unsupported Media Type" for send notification with Postman

Tags: json, curl, postman, iot, kaa

I try send Notification using Kaa sandbox with Postman; but given an error (Unsupported Media Type).

I try with header **"Content-type"**:

1. application/json
2. Octed-Steram

But not solved this problem.

**Scenario is:**

**First** - structure of schema is :

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Notification",
    "namespace": "org.kaa.config",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "message",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Second** - data param is:

```
{"applicationId":"111","schemaId":"139","topicId":"171","type":"USER"}
```

(Hint: value according of my required.)

**Third**:

Json file contend is:

```
{
  "message" : "Hello world!"
}
```

This is error in Postman:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Error 415 Unsupported Media Type</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 415</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendUnicastNotification. Reason:

        <pre>    Unsupported Media Type</pre>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <i>
        <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
    </i>
    <hr/>
</body>
```

And I try with cURL command but given an same error (Unsupported Media Type)

```
curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -F'notification={"applicationId":"111","schemaId":"139","topicId":"171","type":"USER"};type=application/json' -F file=@notification.json "http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification" | python -mjson.tool
```

(Hint: I trying with Notification Demo in Sandbox).

This is reference link :

http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Admin+REST+API#AdminRESTAPI-Sendnotification

Comment: That is old version of API doc. If If you are using latest Kaa, use documentation  from [here](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/#!/Notifications/sendNotification)

Comment: But not very different...

Comment: This is answer-Please check this link : [send Notification in Kaa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541629/how-should-i-implement-rest-api-in-kaa)

Answer (score 0):

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTRzN.png)

or maybe in your notification body schemas any field is optional. you need change your json file. for example:

{"notifId" : "16243", "notifInfo": {"string":"this is info"}, "notifType" : 90, "notifPayload" : "this is payload" }

notifInfo is optional