# How should I implement Rest API in KAA

Tags: rest, curl, post, kaa

I using Kaa sandbox for send notification.

I have to run these codes on window terminals:

```
curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -F 'notification={"applicationId":"3","schemaId":"4","topicId":"1","type":"USER"}; type=application/json' -F file=@notification.json "http://192.168.10.49:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification" | python -mjson.tool
```

And content Json file is according to schemaId:

```
{"message" : "Hello world!"}
```

**Hint:** My command and json file is the same folder!.

When I run curl command on windows terminal given an error (HTTP/1.1 400 Required request part 'notification' is not present)

This is complete information when running and give result:

```
C:\Users\866\mycurl>curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -F 'notification={"applicationId":"3","schemaId":"4","topicId":"1","type":"USER"}; type=application/json' -F file=@notification.json "http://192.168.10.49:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification" | python -mjson.tool
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for type=application:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'type=application'
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'type=application'
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 192.168.10.49...
* TCP_NODELAY set
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 192.168.10.49 (192.168.10.49) port 8080 (#1)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'devuser'
> POST /kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.10.49:8080
> Authorization: Basic ZGV2dXNlcjpkZXZ1c2VyMTIz
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 394
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------96aee635439b1f3c
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [312 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 400 Required request part 'notification' is not present
< Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 13:20:44 GMT
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=19eircy8uykvr1f0lnmj4fah7r;Path=/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Length: 402
< Server: Jetty(9.2.2.v20140723)
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
{ [402 bytes data]
100   796  100   402  100   394   1288   1262 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1430
* Closing connection 1
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Please guide me for resolving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right solution.

I try with connected in the kaa server using ssh command.

**1-** You can access SSH by:

```
$ ssh kaa@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

**2-** And then enter:

**Username:** kaa

**Password:** kaa

And it's solved with little changed send notification command in the new and old for calling REST API.

**3-** This command has been changed:

```
curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -X POST --header 'Content-Type:multipart/form-data' -F'notification={"applicationId":"3","schemaId":"65564","topicId":"1","type":"USER"};type=applicatin/json' --header 'Accept:application/json' 'http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification' -F file=@notification.json
```

And then result of right respone:

[image]